How to change XPS Shader nodes to Principled BSDF
How are the XPS shading nodes changed or converted to Principled BSDF? Is this even possible?
I have several Resident Evil environments and want to convert the shaders so they can be exported to Daz Studio. I purchased a plugin which exports environments to Daz Studio called: Blender to Daz Studio plugin from Blender Market site. I primarily work with Daz.
Thank you in advance for your replies.



Maybe related?: Batch renaming materials to texture name "XPS Shader".
